# WPF create UserControl for a TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I need help at replacing some xaml-code with user control.
I have two tabs in main window and I would like to put the second tab (shown with Header=WCF) in user control.
Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="TesterTool.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:TesterTool"
    xmlns:da ="clr-namespace:TesterTool.DatabaseAccess"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:TesterTool.Converters"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TesterTool"
    Title="TestingTool v1.00" Height="350" Width="725"
    Icon="Icon.ico">

<Window.Resources>
    <converters:BoolVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolVisibilityConverter" />
    <converters:InvertedBoolVisibilityConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="WPF" Margin="-2,0" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="image.png"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="332.gif"

            Width="152"
            Height="39"
           Margin="10,69,194,37"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Visibility="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="tb1"
             Text ="{Binding BoxSerialNumber}"
             Height="23" Margin="128,26,0,0"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="220"
             />
            <TextBox x:Name="tbn2"
             Visibility="{Binding IsViewLogSelected, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolVisibilityConverter}}"
             Height="23" Margin="128,73,8,0"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Text="{Binding HardwareID}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             RenderTransformOrigin="0.494,0.478"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="tbb3"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Height="23"
             Margin="128,116,0,0"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Text="{Binding CompanyContext}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220"/>
            <Label Content="Box Serial Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.526,0.5"/>
            <Label Content="Hardware ID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.526,0.5"/>
            <Label Content="Company Context" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,113,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.526,0.5"/>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" 
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Visibility="{Binding IsTrafficLogSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}">
                <Label Content="Start Date" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Grid.Row="1" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <DatePicker x:Name="dp1"
                    SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Height="25"/>
                <Label Content="End Date" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Grid.Row="1" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <DatePicker x:Name="dp2"
                    SelectedDate="{Binding EndDate}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Height="25"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" 
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Visibility="{Binding IsTransmissionLogSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}">
                <Label Content="Start Date" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Grid.Row="1" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <DatePicker x:Name="dp13"
                    SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Height="25"/>
                <Label Content="End Date" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Grid.Row="1" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <DatePicker x:Name="dp23" 
                    SelectedDate="{Binding EndDate}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Height="25"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" 
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Visibility="{Binding IsCreditLogSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}">
                <Label Content="Log date" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Grid.Row="1" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <DatePicker x:Name="dp12"
                    SelectedDate="{Binding LogDate}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Height="25" Width="102"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" 
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Visibility="{Binding IsViewLogSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}">
            </StackPanel>
            <Label Content="VesselIMO" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.526,0.5" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Content="Select Type" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name ="cb"    
              ItemsSource="{Binding LogTypes}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                Margin="164,26,23,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Grid.Column="1">
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="tb3_Copy"
             Visibility="{Binding IsViewLogSelected, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolVisibilityConverter}}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Height="23"
             Margin="164,73,0,0"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Text="{Binding VesselIMO}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="172" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Button Name ="Button1"
            Content="Submit"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="197,81,0,0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="152"
            Height="39"
            Click="Button1Clicked"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Height="23"
             Margin="164,120,0,0"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Text ="{Binding Counter}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="91"/>
            <Label Content="Number of rows" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,116,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>



        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="WCF">
        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="User Credentials" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="26" Width="96"/>
            <Label Content="Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="26" Width="63"/>
            <Label Content="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="26" Width="60"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="unTB"
                Text="{Binding  Username}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Height="22"
                Margin="103,73,0,0"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="179"
                Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Content="Box ID"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="384,73,0,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Height="26"
                   Width="44"/>
            <Label Content="Software Version" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="384,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Height="26" Width="99"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="boxTB"
                     Text="{Binding BoxID}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     Height="22"
                     Margin="501,73,0,0"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     Width="179"
                     Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBox
                Text ="{Binding SoftwareId}"
                x:Name="SIBox"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Height="22"
                Margin="501,124,0,0"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="179"
                Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Button Content="Create Box" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="538,233,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Height="35" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding CreateBoxCommand}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="pass"
                Text ="{Binding Password}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Height="22"
                Margin="103,120,0,0"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="179"
                Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Does anyone knows how to do this in proper way?

Comment: Everything is fine. I am just trying to figure out how to put 
Tab Item WCF in user control and reuse it in MainWindow.xamel

Comment: What have you tried? Or what is the problem you can't deal alone with? SO is not "write code for me" service. It is possible to use UserControl for TabItem in wpf using data templates, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20939660/1997232).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Put entire Grid and its contents present in your TabItem(WCF) in a user-control, and name this UserControl as WCFTabUserControl.
2. Reference the namespace in your Window tag like : `xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"`
3. Use your user-control :

   ```
   <TabItem Header="WCF">
        <uc:WCFTabUserControl/>
   </TabItem>
   ```