# TabControl - Display N TabItems depending on List<List<T>> dimension

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

My WPF Window imports a `List<List<T>>`.
I want to display each `List<T>` in a ListView (and other informations), each of `List<T>` may be in separate TabItems, but I don't know in advance how many List I will have. I have one Template done to display one `List<T>`, but I would like to repeat it in each TabItem.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939660/using-a-datatemplate-for-the-tabitems-in-a-tabcontrol?rq=1 ?

Comment: @o_weisman in fact this is similar question, but not totally (anyway interesting to read), because this works if I have a List<T>, then display each object in a TabItem. And what I have is a List<List<T>> I would like to group in each TabItem. Anyway I guess this is the direction I may follow, create a custom object, which object will have a List<T> inside, I work on that right now, then will come back if I find a solution, thanks for it.

Comment: @o_weisman So after checking all I confirm this is a good way to solve my problem (May I delete my question/mark as duplicate?). It is not possible to make if for `List<List<T>>`, but if I convert this to a `List<Object>`, and this Object will have a property where I copy `List<T>`, it is working perfectly, thanks a lot for it.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance

Comment: @o_weisman May I ask you to make an answer please? I cannot close the question as there is no answer.

Comment: I think it's better to mark it as a duplicate

Comment: Is this considered as duplicate as it's not the same question?Can I do this on my own question(don't find the link), or could you do it yourself?Thanks

Comment: I really don't know but to me it seems a duplicate as it is fundamentally the same question. I'll mark it as such and see what other members think.

Comment: I believed no, because the question was about `List<List<T>>`(technicaly not the same as `List<T>`), anyway this solved the question so just accepted the Duplicate. Thanks again, as that really helped a lot.